# SSRS & PowerShell: Create and set schedule for reports?

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, schedule

Is there a way to create and then change the schedule for all reports in a folder on SSRS in one click? I have a lot of reports and I'm not aware of a way but doing one by one.

========================================

EDIT: 8/30/18

I'm having some trouble creating a schedule (and then I still need to set it to all reports):

```
$ScheduleDefinition = New-Object SSRS.ScheduleDefinition
$ScheduleDefinition.StartDateTime = [DateTime] "01/01/2018 12:00:00 AM"
$ScheduleDefinition.EndDate = [DateTime] "01/01/2050 12:00:00 AM"
$ScheduleDefinition.EndDateSpecified = "True"

$CreateSchedule = $ReportServerProxy.CreateSchedule("Report Schedule",$ScheduleDefinition,$null)
```

Results in:

```
Cannot convert argument "ScheduleDefinition", with value: "SSRS.ScheduleDefinition", for "CreateSchedule" to type "SSRS.ScheduleDefinition": "Cannot convert the "SSRS.ScheduleDefinition" value of type "SSRS.ScheduleDefinition" to type "SSRS.ScheduleDefinition"."
```

How I'm making my connection:

```
$ReportServerUri = "http://localhost/reportserver/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl"
$ReportServerProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportServerUri -UseDefaultCredential -Namespace "SSRS"
```

Comment: You can setup a shared schedule. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/new-shared-schedule-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @aduguid, right, I did that. But how do I apply it to ALL of my reports in one fell swoop? I downloaded the PS ReportingServicesTools but couldn't seem to figure out a way to get it to update all the reports within a given folder (or two) with said schedule.

Right now, I will have to do this manually to 15 reports x 13 servers x 2 clients. A ton of work.

Comment: Here's an example of updating multiple SSRS subscriptions with PowerShell  https://www.warrenestes.com/update-multiple-ssrs-subscriptions/

Comment: @aduguid, I found that article before posting this question but it didn't help me much. No matter, I did make a little bit of progress (see my edit above), however, I'm still not able/not sure how to actually update each of the reports I found with a snapshot schedule.

Comment: The other option would be to write a `MERGE` statement in a transaction in T-SQL, to update the `dbo.Subcription` table directly.

Comment: @aduguid...hmm. I don't know if I can use that method in Octopus Deploy which is why I'm trying to stick to PowerShell.

Comment: Can you show me the output of these two commands? `$ReportServerProxy.CreateSchedule`, `$ScheduleDefinition.GetType().Fullname` I want to see the constructor for CreateSchedule and the actual underlying type of your definition

Comment: Sure @Matt. `$ReportServerProxy.CreateSchedule` yields `OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                                                              
-------------------                                                                                                                                              
string CreateSchedule(string Name, SSRS.ScheduleDefinition, 3osn0ijl, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null ScheduleDefinition, string SiteUrl)`. `$SD.GetType().FullName` = `SSRS.ScheduleDefinition`

Comment: Well that yeilded nothing particularily useful. Thanks though. I assumed they would not match _exactly_ but they appear to have here.

Comment: I wouldn't think creating a schedule would be so tough. I'm not PowerShell expert but I know my way around and I've never been stuck on a script like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create Schedule**

You can create a shared schedule using [`CreateSchedule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createschedule?view=sqlserver-2016) function:

```
$svcUrl = 'http://your-server-name/ReportServer/reportservice2010.asmx'
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -Namespace 'RS' -Uri $svcUrl -UseDefaultCredential

$definition = New-Object RS.ScheduleDefinition  
$scheduleID = ""
$definition.StartDateTime =  [DateTime] "01/01/2018 12:00:00 AM"
$recurrence = New-Object RS.DailyRecurrence
$recurrence.DaysInterval = 1
$definition.Item = $recurrence

$scheduleID = $svc.CreateSchedule("My Schedule",$definition, $null);
```

**Set History Snapshot Schedule for all reports in a folder**

Then you can first get all reports using [`ListChildren`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren?view=sqlserver-2016#ReportService2010_ReportingService2010_ListChildren_System_String_System_Boolean_) function. Then for each report, you can use [`SetItemHistoryOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.setitemhistoryoptions?view=sqlserver-2016#ReportService2010_ReportingService2010_SetItemHistoryOptions_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_ReportService2010_ScheduleDefinitionOrReference_) to set history snapshot schedule using the shared schedule which you created in previous step:

```
$sharedSchedule = New-Object RS.ScheduleReference
$sharedSchedule.ScheduleID = $scheduleID 
$reports = $svc.ListChildren("/", $true) | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Report" }
foreach ($report in $reports) {
    $svc.SetItemHistoryOptions($report.Path, $true, $true, $sharedSchedule)
}
```

Comment: Reza, you sir are a savior! So, turns out the issue was that I was using the wrong 'namespace' and 'class' (SSRS vs RS) and then you did some additional things with the recurrence, etc.

My script is working flawlessly now!

Comment: Cool! The class name and namespace parameters are not important and can be everything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new [Powershell Module](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools) to automate tasks on the Report Server.

Have a look at the Cmdlets Set-RsSubscription and New-RsScheduleXml.

Comment: Thanks @abbgrade. I was actually using that module initially but was struggling so I went back to the classic one. I can give it another try. Can you help clarify something for me as I wasn't able to quite understand the difference...what is a subscription? If I go into the UI and set a schedule for a particular report...is that effectively me setting a subscription? Or is a subscription something different?

Comment: A report can have many subscriptions and a subscription can have a schedule. The subscription defines the parameter values of the report and delivery options like paths on the file system or E-Mail addresses. The schedule triggers a subscription in a defined interval.

Answer (score 0):

If powershell is not a constraint for your requirement, I can suggest to use SSIS for this by using below steps:

1. Setup your all set of reports that you wish to schedule by using method explained in this link: 
   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/93504/
2. then you can schedule this SSIS package (created in step#1) using SQL server Agent job. You can refer below link regarding scheduling SSIS package through SQL Server agent job
   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/220/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/
3. then by using Stored procedure: **sp_update_schedule**, you can change Sql Server Agent job schedule at any point of time on a single clink from your UI or executing this procedure as per your need. See below link for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-schedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks @Aftab, this may be a fall back option as I do have the ability to run SQL statements from within Octopus Deploy but OD is built on PowerShell so I'd prefer to use that if possible. I will certainly keep this recommendation in my back pocket.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one more option that can fulfill your requirement.

1. Setup your all set of reports that you wish to schedule by using method explained in this link: http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2018/08/execute-ssrs-subscription-on-demand.html
2. then you can schedule batch file (created in step#1) using SQL server Agent job. You can refer below link regarding scheduling Batch file through SQL Server agent job https://sharminjahan625.wordpress.com/2013/08/30/384/
3. then by using Stored procedure: sp_update_schedule, you can change Sql Server Agent job schedule at any point of time on a single clink from your UI or executing this procedure as per your need. See below link for more details.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-schedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is more of a long comment but I think this might help.

I have an older version of SSRS 2008 around and have an unrelated (to this answer) PowerShell module that I use for it. I mention this because when I make SSRS objects I reference the namespace of my connection proxy object. If I don't do that I get type mismatch errors *similar* to what you are experiencing.

```
# Get the namespace
$ssrsServiceNamespace = $connectservice.GetType().namespace

# Create the schedule definition
$ScheduleDefinition = New-Object "$ssrsServiceNamespace.ScheduleDefinition"
$ScheduleDefinition.StartDateTime = [DateTime] "01/01/2018 12:00:00 AM"
$ScheduleDefinition.EndDate = [DateTime] "01/01/2050 12:00:00 AM"
$ScheduleDefinition.EndDateSpecified = "True"

# Add it to SSRS
$connectservice.CreateSchedule("test report schedule",$ScheduleDefinition)
```

The result of which is a GUID? for me. Presumably for the new schedule entity.

Comment: I was having some issue figuring out what you real issue is since there appears to be a few issues discussed in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, but that yielded the same result :(.

My two remaining issues as far as what I have planned for this script is 1) create schedule and 2) assign it to a set of reports (loop through report variable after I find the ones matching my criteria).

I don't understand why it doesn't like this :(.